# Server Error in '/' Application while deploying a Angular App on Azure

Tags: angular, azure, visual-studio-code, cloud

I am new to Azure. I am trying simple Azure cloud deployments.
I have this basic demo Angular app which is perfectly working in local environment. I did all the Azure setup & its successfully deploying. But when i browse the website its giving server error. Any inputs please.
Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are deploying your code in the App service, please check its **Default documents**.
It's available in the Appservice's **Settings -> Configuration -> Default documents**.
If **index.html** is not listed in the document list, please add it.

**Screenshot for reference:**

[image: index.html]

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a **web.config** which tell Azure that you are using a Node application and you need to start it.

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
      <rewrite>
        <rules>
          <rule name="Angular" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
              <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
              <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
          </rule>
        </rules>
      </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Hi @Sajeetharan , Thanks for your input. Yes i added web.config file under src & the rebuild it. I can see web.config in dist folder too but still unable to get rid of that error.

Answer (score 0):

Recived the same error on initial deploy. I had to do as @Sajeetharan suggested for Default documents (index.html needs to be at the top).
Under Path Mappings -> Physical Path I had to add **NAME_OF_MY_PROJECT** so it looked like this -> site\wwwroot\**NAME_OF_MY_PROJECT**
Finally I had to add a web.config to root of the project, (I also have one in my src for allowing .json to be served from assets and start node).

web.config:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <configuration>
       <system.webServer>
          <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="error.htm"/>
          <customErrors mode="Off"/>
       </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```

src/web.config:

Answer (score 0):

There's three things that you need to do.

1. In Azure, on your App Service, Development Tools > Advanced Tools > Go > Debug Console, Select CMD > Site > wwwroot > Remove all the files there. There's a great chance that those files are corrupt.
2. Publish your App again to your service, once done,
3. navigate to the root folder and check your how your file structure
   is. if your file structure is **wwwroot/your_app_name** , then  on
   Configuration > Path mappings, your Virtual applications and
   directories should be **site\wwwroot\your_app_name** else it should be **site\wwwroot**

I have seen a lot of suggestions that the Virtual applications and
directories should be **site\wwwroot\your_app_name** that is not true. Your app structure should dictate that.