# Angular app shows error after Azure deploy

Tags: angular, angularjs, azure, azure-web-app-service, web-deployment

I have an Angular App that shows a map using the "leaflet" package and afterwards draws some data from a file on that map.
The App works perfectly on localhost but when I deploy it to "Azure Web App" it shows the following error:
[Error on server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3Emp.png)

Has anyone seen that error before and knows how to solve it?

Thanks in advance,
Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you [SnehaAgrawal-MSFT](https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/users/141732/snehaagrawal-msft.html) ,Posting your [suggestion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/23282/deployed-angular-web-app-keeps-getting-you-do-not.html) as an answer to help other community members.

"Just to confirm in your Application Settings if you have any of the files sited here in the /home/site/wwwroot folder? If not, this could be a reason for this error. If so, recommend you go to your app service, under settings Click Configuration > Path mappings > You will see "Virtual applications and directories.

Your virtual path should be "/" and physical path should be "site/wwwroot/" Change your Physical path to "site/wwwroot/'appname'" "appname" should be whatever the name of your application is. Or it should be whatever folder is inside of your "dist".

You can refer to this  blog for [How to Deploy an Angular application to Azure Web Service](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/deploy-angular-application-on-azure-web-service-960e441bb13d) "

For more information please refer the below links:

. [Server Error in '/' Application while deploying a Angular App on Azure | SO THREAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67584522/server-error-in-application-while-deploying-a-angular-app-on-azure) .

. [Unable to deploy React JS application on Azure App service | SO THREAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63485396/unable-to-deploy-react-js-application-on-azure-app-service)

Comment: sorry for the late reply. your answer fixed the problem, thank you so much :))